# binding attribute of a variable to another variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the following class:

```
@interface Location : RKObject <NSCoding>{
    NSNumber*  _latitude;
    NSNumber*  _longitude;
    NSNumber*  _route_order;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* latitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* longitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* route_order;

- (id) initWithLatitude:(double) lat  andLongitude:(double) longt;

@end
```

I would like to bind the coordinate.latitude with _latitude doubleValue and the same thing with longitude. So the value of coordinate.latitude is always set with whatever value is currently at _latitude. Is this possible in objective-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "magical" bind in Objective-C what you could do instead of synthesizing properties is writing accessors *(which is what `@synthesize` really do at compilation in fact)*, something like that :

```
@interface Location : RKObject <NSCoding> {
    NSNumber*  _route_order;
    CLLocationCoordinate coordinate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber* latitude;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber* longitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* route_order;

- (id) initWithLatitude:(double) lat  andLongitude:(double) longt;

@end
```

When implementing accessors instead of synthesizing them, the retain / assign / readonly keyword is somewhat *informative*. In this example I've used assign because your properties won't actually retain references passed.

In Implementation:

```
@implementation Location

// note the absence of @synthesize there

- (NSNumber *)latitude  { return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:latitude];  }
- (NSNumber *)longitude { return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:longitude]; }
- (void)setLatitude:(NSNumber *)latitude   { coordinate.latitude  = [latitude doubleValue];  }
- (void)setLongitude:(NSNumber *)longitude { coordinate.longitude = [longitude doubleValue]; }

@end
```

Another alternative, related to "binding" techniques is [KVO](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html), but a bit off-topic imho since this a bit too complex for such a simple case.

Comment: but there's no way to set that coordinate.latitude to latitude?

Comment: You can by writing the setter and changing readonly by assign.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any way to do what you are asking. But if you misstated your request, and want the `latitude` *property* to access the coordinate's latitude (rather than the `_latitude` *ivar*), it's a simple matter of writing custom getter and setter methods:

```
- (NSNumber *)latitude {
    return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:coordinate.latitude];
}

- (void)setLatitude:(NSNumber *)value {
    coordinate.latitude = [value doubleValue];
}
```

You could then get rid of the `_latitude` ivar completely.

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like you want to do is this:

```
@synthesize latitude = _latitude;
```

That will make the synthesized setter and getter methods for your latitude property change your _latitude ivar.

Comment: I don't think you're getting my question.. I want coordinate.latitude to bind with NSNumber latitude and same goes for longitude

Comment: coordinate is a CLCoordinateLocation2D here, FYI